# Hide and show rows on every sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a script that works fine for a while now for 1 sheet. I'm looking for a way to make it work for all of the sheets. So no restriction to "GetSheetByName". Is this posible?

Script i'm using right now:

```
function hideShow() {
  
  var sh= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Winkel Roosters");
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,25,sh.getLastRow()-2,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=3;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==1) {
      sh.hideRows(i+3);
    }
    if(vA[i][0]==0) {
      sh.showRows(i+3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have provided an answer below that should be able to fix your issue. Kindly check if it does work with yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it looped on all sheets in your spreadsheet.

#### Code:

```
// Get all sheets
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
// Loop script into all of those sheets
ss.forEach(function (sh){
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,25,sh.getLastRow()-2,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=3;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==1) {
      sh.hideRows(i+3);
    }
    if(vA[i][0]==0) {
      sh.showRows(i+3);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes! This is perfect!

Thank you NaziA!

Comment: Hi @Roy, If your issue was resolved, kindly push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer